# Corrigir Problema de encoding ao exportar para csv de um arquivo scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Como eu posso corrigir o problema de encoding ao salvar o arquivo em csv? este problema está acontecendo somente quando salvo em csv.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
from scrapy import *
from projeto_iruan.items import *
import csv

class imprensaNacional(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imprensaNacional'
    start_urls = ['http://www.imprensanacional.gov.br/leiturajornal?data=11-09-2018&secao=dou3']
    imprensaNacional = "imprensaNacional.csv"
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': csv
    }

    def __init__(self):
        # empty outputfile
        open(self.imprensaNacional, "w").close()

    def parse(self, response):
        url_base = 'http://www.imprensanacional.gov.br/'
        script = response.xpath('//*[@class="span8 hierarchy-wrapper"]//*[contains(text(),"AVISO DE LICITA")]')
        for urls in script:
            links = urls.xpath('.//@href').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
            link_completo = url_base + links
            yield Request(url=link_completo, callback=self.parseAviso)

    def parseAviso(self, response):
        with open(self.imprensaNacional, "a") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
            conteudo = response.xpath('//*[@class="journal-content-article"]')
            for info in conteudo:
                titulo = info.xpath(u'.//*[@class="identifica"]/text()[contains(.,"N\xba")]').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                pregao = info.xpath(u'.//*[@class="identifica"]/text()[contains(.,"N\xba")]').extract_first().split()[3].encode('utf-8')
                uasg = info.xpath(u'.//*[@class="identifica"]/text()[contains(.,"N\xba")]').extract_first().split()[6].encode('utf-8')
                tipo = info.xpath('.//*[@class="identifica"]/text()[contains(.,"AVISO")]').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                pregoeiro = info.xpath('.//*[@class="assina"]/text()').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                descricao = info.xpath('.//*[@class="dou-paragraph"]/text()').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                dou = info.xpath('.//*[@class="dou-paragraph"]/text()[contains(.,"(")]').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                orgao = info.xpath('.//*[@class="orgao-dou-data"]/text()').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                data_publicacao = info.xpath('.//*[@class="publicado-dou-data"]/text()').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                edicao_dou = info.xpath('.//*[@class="edicao-dou-data"]/text()').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                secao = info.xpath('.//*[@class="secao-dou"]/text()').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                pagina = info.xpath('.//*[@class="secao-dou-data"]/text()').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                writer.writerow([titulo,tipo,pregao,uasg,dou,data_publicacao,edicao_dou,secao,pagina,orgao,pregoeiro,response.url,descricao])
                yield {'Titulo': titulo, 'Tipo': tipo, 'Pregao': pregao, 'UASG': uasg,
                       'DOU': dou, 'DataPublicacao': data_publicacao, 'Edicao': edicao_dou,
                       'Secao': secao, 'Pagina': pagina, 'Orgao': orgao, 'Pregoeiro': pregao,
                       'Url': response.url, 'Descricao': descricao}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está encodificando suas strings em utf-8, mas parece que está utilizando um programa de planilhas para lê-las que está não está reconhecendo este encoding.

Se está usando o excel, na hora de importar para o excel, use a caixa de diálogo de importação (ao invés de simplesmente abrir o arquivo) assim poderá selecionar a opção de encoding utf-8. Uma outra alternativa é tentar usar o encoding cp1252 que costuma ser o encoding padrão do excel em português. Troque todos os `.encode('utf-8')` por `.encode('cp1252')` e veja se resolve.

Quanto a linhas duplas, você está abrindo o arquivo em modo texto, e como o módulo `csv` do python 2 espera um arquivo em formato binário, você acaba tendo duplicidade das quebras de linha. Troque a linha

```
with open(self.imprensaNacional, "a") as f:
```

por

```
with open(self.imprensaNacional, "ab") as f:
```

para usar o modo binário.